# Update field by checking the combination of parameters

Tags: sql, dynamic, sql-update, case, combinations

I would like to do a SQL dynamic SQL update statement where I will check all combinations between two fields like...

MS|TO or MS|1

... and update the effected ones. I'm able to select all combination from an other table. How can I do an dynamic CASE clause with WHEN brackets for each combinations.

```
UPDATE dbo.KonfigTableOne
   SET P01Dec =  ( CASE  
                   WHEN (Ap.Ke01 + '|' + Ap.Ke02 = '*|*')  THEN (SELECT FACTOR FROM Factor  WHERE SHORTCUT = '*|*') 
                   WHEN (Ap.Ke01 + '|' + Ap.Ke02 = 'MS|*') THEN (SELECT FACTOR FROM Factor  WHERE SHORTCUT = 'MS|*') 
                   WHEN (Ap.Ke01 + '|' + Ap.Ke02 = 'ME|*') THEN (SELECT FACTOR FROM Factor  WHERE SHORTCUT = 'ME|*') 
                   WHEN (Ap.Ke01 + '|' + Ap.Ke02 = '*|1')  THEN (SELECT FACTOR FROM Factor  WHERE SHORTCUT = '*|1') 
                   WHEN (Ap.Ke01 + '|' + Ap.Ke02 = '*|2')  THEN (SELECT FACTOR FROM Factor  WHERE SHORTCUT = '*|2') 
                   WHEN (Ap.Ke01 + '|' + Ap.Ke02 = 'MS|1') THEN (SELECT FACTOR FROM Factor  WHERE SHORTCUT = 'MS|1') 
                   WHEN (Ap.Ke01 + '|' + Ap.Ke02 = 'MS|2') THEN (SELECT FACTOR FROM Factor  WHERE SHORTCUT = 'MS|2') 
                   WHEN (Ap.Ke01 + '|' + Ap.Ke02 = 'ME|1') THEN (SELECT FACTOR FROM Factor  WHERE SHORTCUT = 'ME|1') 
                   WHEN (Ap.Ke01 + '|' + Ap.Ke02 = 'ME|2') THEN (SELECT FACTOR FROM Factor  WHERE SHORTCUT = 'ME|2') 
                   END )
  FROM dbo.KonfigTableOne AS Ap CROSS JOIN
       dbo.KonfigTableTwo AS Ep
 WHERE (Ap.P02Dec = 1)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Why don't you directly use the condition, completely removing the CASE ? Like: `UPDATE dbo.KonfigTableOne
   SET P01Dec = (SELECT FACTOR FROM Factor  WHERE SHORTCUT = Ap.Ke01 + '|' + Ap.Ke02)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query can be simplified to:

```
UPDATE ap
    SET P01Dec = (SELECT FACTOR FROM Factor  WHERE SHORTCUT = Ap.Ke01 + '|' + Ap.Ke02) 
    FROM dbo.KonfigTableOne Ap CROSS JOIN
         dbo.KonfigTableTwo Ep
    WHERE Ap.P02Dec = 1 AND
          Ap.Ke01 + '|' + Ap.Ke02 IN ( . . . )  -- valid options here;
```

I don't see a role for dynamic SQL here.

That said, your query is non-sensical if `KonfigTableTwo` has more than one row.  This results in multiple possible updates to `KonfigTableOne`.  However, databases will update the row only once with an arbitrary match.

I would recommend that you ask a NEW question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.